# esc key doesn't work, only fn + esc

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra

So there's probably some app that's responsible for this, but I'm not sure how to find it.

I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>  in:

- Karabiner-events: it echoes 'escape' as it should
- according to OS X keyboard-viewer <kbd>Esc</kbd> is never pressed.

But <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>  does work (also in OS X keyboard-viewer).

I have no clue where to look for. 
I saw this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65974/os-x-esc-key-stops-working-randomly) but I already disabled Siri and Speech and rebooted.

Where can I find more info how to deal with this?

I'm on the latest update of High Sierra 10.13.4.

Using an app called 'Key Codes', it logged:

- pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> : nothing
- pressing <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>  (first fn, than esc):

  ```
  Modifier Change
      Keys:       
      Key Code:       65535 / 0xffff
      Modifiers:      8388864 / 0x800100 ⓘ

  Key Down
      Characters: 
      Unicode:        27 / 0x1b
      Keys:           Escape
      Key Code:       53 / 0x35
      Modifiers:      8388864 / 0x800100 ⓘ

  Key Up
      Characters: 
      Unicode:        27 / 0x1b
      Keys:           Escape
      Key Code:       53 / 0x35
      Modifiers:      8388864 / 0x800100 ⓘ

  Modifier Change
      Keys:       
      Key Code:       65535 / 0xffff
      Modifiers:      256 / 0x100 ⓘ
  ```

In xev, when I press 'esc' nothing is echoed. But when I press fn+esc, I get the following output:

```
FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967201 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

PropertyNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    atom 0x101 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 979893442, state PropertyNewValue

KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 979893799, (144,-11), root:(161,702),
    state 0x0, keycode 61 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 979893895, (144,-11), root:(161,702),
    state 0x0, keycode 61 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
```

For the full output of `xmodmap -pk` I uploaded it [here](https://textuploader.com/dndlw). The most notable lines (I guess) is:

```
 61         0xff1b (Escape) 0x0000 (NoSymbol)       0xff1b (Escape)
 79         0xff1b (Escape) 0x0000 (NoSymbol)       0xff1b (Escape)
```

Comment: If Karabiner events sees "escape" as it should, it's sending the correct scan code, however, what you're getting for `fn-Esc` doesn't look right (`Esc` should be code 61).  See [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317556/119271) for how to use `xev` (included with macOS) to obtain scan codes.  Also try testing in Safe Mode

Comment: I am using Karabiner Elements which allegedly doesn't register FN. To make this even more mysterious: 
Key Codes on my MacbookAir returns for Escape (w or w/o FN) 
>>Keys: Escape / Key Code: 53/0x35 / Modifiers: 256/0x100<< 
EventViewer simply returns: >>0x29/escape<< and 
xev returns: >>keycode 61 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape)<<

Comment: yeah I don't feel the problem is getting much clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found out WHY it's suddenly this way. But I found a solution. In karabiner-elements I bound escape to escape and this overwrote whatever happened before :) Should've thought of this earlier

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your keyboard has got the correct country identification and ISO/Ansi setting, you might try "xev" in Terminal app.
After some moments it will open a small window left on top of your screen.
Just press "esc" once, then any letter, next press "fn" and "esc". Last: Cmd-dot to stop the output.
Depending on what your Terminal window tells you you might get some hint.

Another command in Terminal "xmodmap -pk" delivers a list of your keyboard's Keycodes and Keysym-values.
Maybe there is s.th. unusual shown there. You might post relevant output here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @clemsam_lang but neither xev or xmodmap come pre-installed in OSX. I looked it up and it seems a tool for ubuntu.. perhaps you know how to installed it in OSX?

So I went looking for other alternatives. I found an app called 'Key Codes' and edited the post with the results

Comment: You will need to install an X11/X.Org server to get xev and xmodmap. This used to come bundled with OS X, but now you have to download and install it separately from [xquartz.org](https://www.xquartz.org).

Comment: I added the results in the topic... but not sure what else to do with it

Comment: Actually I had quite a similar problem with a non-Apple keyboard whose Windows "context menu key" showed no reaction until I installed a special  file "ApplePS2SmartTouchPad.kext" which down in its deepest recesses offered a setting "Make context menu key into key". There I assigned -quite randomly- key number "16" to it which Karabiner (EventViewer) now sees as "scan_previous_track" – and successfully remaps to any key I want. (There is a more advanced "VoodooPS2Controller.kext" that's mainly used in hackintosh devices; that one does not work with my older keyboard, though.)

Answer (score 1):

As an update from **Nov 2023**:

I've tried everything here and what I could find around the internet but it was the **Loom app** in my case. Once I killed the app, everything worked again.

**UPD:**

Loom support investigating the issue.[image]

Comment: same here! the loom guys should be sued for this!!!

Comment: @abbood let's upvote the answer to bring it more attention. I guess these days a lot of Loom users face this issue because of the app.

Comment: haha done, you're new to this eh? lol

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the BetterTouchTool. I removed it and all of a sudden my ESC key worked again like before :)

Answer (score 0):

All software solutions did not work out for me so used hardware one. Literally made fn key always pressed. Now my K1280 keyboard upper row is the same as genuine apple keyboard.

Comment: How did you “literally make all fn keys pressed?”  Explaining *how* to do something goes a long way in making a good answer.

Comment: I taped **fn** key carefully so it's always pressed. It does not look that ugly and it does its job very well. Finally I got Esc key in VIM! :)